# "RuntimeError unknown class:" when accessing result of a "joins" operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When trying to access the result of a `Model.joins(ActiveRecord::Relation)` operation, an error occurs.

The models are as follows:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :android_device

    def Device.find_devices_by_attributes(device_params)
        android_devices = AndroidDevice.find_android_devices_by_attributes(device_params[:android_device_attributes])

        if (!android_devices.nil?) && (!android_devices.empty?)
            devices_android_device = Device.joins(android_devices)   <--- this is the line the error occures on.
        end
    end
end

class AndroidDevice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :device

    def AndroidDevice.find_android_devices_by_attributes (android_params)
        android_devices = AndroidDevice.where("android_id = ?", android_params[:android_id])
    end
end
```

Log shows:

```
2014-05-21T08:46:14.719594+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 87ms
2014-05-21T08:46:14.721376+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError (unknown class: AndroidDevice):
```

Both, `Device` and `AndroidDevice`, are created via command `rails g scaffold ...`

I do not understand why `AndroidDevice` is an unknown class.

Comment: The stack trace should point you to a specific line in your project's code - what's on that line?

Comment: btw, as a convention, when doing class methods like you have, you would either write `def self.find_android_devices....`, or wrap the methods in a `class << self` block and just write `def find_android_devices...`

Comment: thanks for the advice Max.
the line which the error occured is:
 devices_android_device = Device.joins(android_devices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.joins` with ActiveRecord::Relation as parameter.

Probably you want http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge functionality.

Comment: so u are suggesting Device.all.merge?

Comment: @user3659968, you should try it yourself. Does this solution work?

Comment: i have tried this suggestion. for this purpose, i used the form:

Device.joins(:android_device).merge(AndroidDevice.where())

so in the context of original code, changes is on the error line

    devices_android_device = Device.joins(android_devices)

to 

    devices_android_device = Device.joins(:android_device).merge(android_devices)


Thanks for bringing merge to attention Sergey and thats why i accepted this as answer.

however, i do not quite understand the merge!. what is the general convention for the ! function? whats the difference between merge and merge!?

Comment: @user3659968, the difference between merge and merge! – just look at the source code – merge uses merge! in case of it is not Array and not nil or false. The general convention in Ruby means that this method is dangerous. Try to google "bang methods in Ruby". Do you have other questions?